# IE anchor selector inheritance

Tags: css, internet-explorer, inheritance

I have some html with the basic structure

```
<nav>
     <div>
    <a href="">
        <div class="navlink" data-link="home">
            <span class="top"></span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <div id="index-03"></div>
    <a href="">
        <div class="navlink" data-link="resume">
            <span class="top"></span>
        </div>
    </a>
        ...
     </div>
</nav>
```

and CSS like this

```
a {
    color: #000;
}

div.navlink span {
    background: red;
}

nav {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    right: 35px;
    color: #fff;
}

nav span {
    margin:auto;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

nav span.top {
    top: 45%;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 50;
}

nav span.bottom {
    top: 41%;
    font-size: 16px;
    z-index: 50;
    color: #fff;
}

.navlink:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 50;


   color: #fff;
}
```

In every browser I can test but IE 6-8 the position and color for the .navlink span work but in IE it is applying the highest parent selector `a {}`. This does not make sense to me how do I make position and color apply to the span in all browsers including IE

Comment: You realise that nesting a `div` (block level element) within an `a` (in-line element) is invalid?

Comment: Are you using the [HTML5 shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv)?

Comment: @David Thomas: that is incorrect - block level `a` elements are valid in html5.

Comment: @Nico Burns: It's still not a good idea to do what @David Thomas said. Some browsers (hello Firefox) can behave strangely with it.

Comment: @Nico: without publishing his Doctype, it felt safe to assume that he was using HTML4. But, you're right, it is certainly valid in HTML5.

Comment: @David Thomas No where in the w3c rules does it say that it only says that anchors cannot be self nesting

Comment: @David Thomas: He's using a `nav` element, a more logical guess would be that he's using HTML5.

Comment: @Nico my doctype is html 5 I figured you could tell it's HTML5 just because I am using data-* and the nav elements which are not valid tags in html 4 anyway here is my doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Comment: @zobgib: you raise valid points. My apologies for missing the blatantly obvious... =)

Comment: @David Thomas: he is using the `<nav>` tag which is html5 only, but that is quite easy to miss.

@thirtydot: Didn't know about that - I've never had any problems, but you might be right.

@zoglib: `<a>` tags can only be inline in html4, and it is invalid to have a block level tag within an inline tag.

Comment: @BoltClock if you make your comment into an answer I will accept it Nico beat you to the answer but you were faster :P my only question is what happens in IE if JS is disabled then?

Comment: @zobgib: Well, added my answer.

Comment: @Nico Burns: [This is the sort of bug](http://remysharp.com/2009/08/10/defining-the-vomit-bug/) I was talking about. I forget the specifics.

Comment: @thirtydot that's pretty cool, I will modify my links to be blocks inside the div's that should prevent that bug :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `<nav>` is an HTML5 element, IE6 to 8 doesn't recognize it. Your styles won't be applied to elements that it doesn't recognize to be real DOM elements.

You need to inform IE of the presence of HTML5 elements using something such as the [HTML5 shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv).

> my only question is what happens in IE if JS is disabled then?

I think you're pretty much screwed then.

Comment: What happens with JS disabled. It is hard for me to check because I am on a mac Right now the site is fully functional with or without js I would like to keep it that way.

Comment: @zobgib: What happens is what you saw before applying the HTML5 shiv: styles that apply to `nav` don't take effect at all.

Comment: So then it would be better for the time being to use <div id='nav/footer'> instead of <nav/footer> elements for styling purposes?

Comment: @zobgib: If compatibility + noscript support is a real concern, I would say yes.

Answer (score 2):

IE 6-8 do not support the `<nav>` tag. You must use javascript code such as [this](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv) to enable styling of the new html5 tags or stick to div tags.